# Emulator gets stuck on Phone is starting screen while building [ProjectName].Android Xamarin.Forms application from Visual Studio

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-emulator, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to build and test my Xamarin.Forms Android application on Emulator from Visual Studio
The emulator is getting stuck on the screen

[image: Emulator is getting stuck]

Screen got belowed message for a single time and after clicking **Wait**, it again started showing **Phone is starting**

[image]

Build output is mentioned below,

```
2>Starting deployment to pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28 ...
2>Starting emulator pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28 ...
2>Checking HAXM compatibility.
2>Installing HAXM...
2>HAXM installer not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\silent_install.bat
2>Running non-accelerated
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -no-boot-anim -no-accel -avd pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28 -prop monodroid.avdname=pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28
2>Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
2>emulator: WARNING: x86 emulation may not work without hardware acceleration!
2>emulator: WARNING: Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.
2>Failed to open /usr/local/google/home/joshuaduong/emu/master/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/qemu-android-deps/windows_msvc-x86_64/qemu.conf, err: 2
2>dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture
2>dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
2>dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
2>dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
2>audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
2>dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
2>dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
2>audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
2>emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined (qrc:/html/js/location-mock-web-channel.js:130, (null))
2>emulator: INFO: boot completed
2>emulator: INFO: boot time 829388 ms
2>emulator: Increasing screen off timeout, logcat buffer size to 2M.
2>emulator: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.
```

**UPDATE**

I found the message given in the image below, after launching emulator separately from Device Manager and building Android solution.

[image]

And this is the output shown:

```
2>Starting deployment to pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28 ...
2>Starting emulator pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28 ...
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -no-boot-anim -avd pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28 -prop monodroid.avdname=pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28
2>emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature.
2>Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.
2>Emulator pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28 cannot be started.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 17 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

But still there are no errors in output window after clicking either Yes or No on deployment errors popup.

Comment: First of all, create a new android emulator, if it works normally, Then If it still have this issue, please open your `Android SDKs and Tools` , update all contents to the latest, if it worked as normal.https://imgur.com/a/HGNBV30

Comment: Based on your error message, pleases check if you install HAMX like this sceenshot.https://imgur.com/a/xQCOmfB  VS support Hardware acceleration for emulator performance, you can refer to it  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=macos

Comment: HAMX installation worked. It made my emulator running but I am uable to run my application on emulator and it is not showing my app on app drawer also. Any idea?

Comment: Please open your Android project properties, Check the `Compile using Android version(Target Framework)`, If it was setted to the latest(If you want to run it in android 9.0 emulator, please set the Target Framework to Android 9.0 or later) like this sceenshot. https://imgur.com/a/J2Smpg7

Comment: It is set to 9.0 already in my project properties. Any other solution?

Comment: Do you find some errors in output window? When you run your application. Can you provide a demo?

Comment: No there are no errors shown on output window. When I close emulator it shows a popup "There are some deployment errors. Want to continue?" Yes or No. But when I click either on Yes or No there are no errors shown on output windows. I will update question with warning popup soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own qeustion.

The first issue was with HAXM, which was not installed.

Then about the deployment error, in my case the name of the emulator was changed from the default one from Android Device Manager. So I changed it back to the default name, the same which is given on the time of adding new device(ex. Nexus 5X).

It worked for my case and then it took so long to get built and deployed!

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing, please do not forget to accept your answer after two days, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to reset the emulator.
Steps:

1. open Android Device Manager in visual studio.
2. open menu and start with factory reset.
   Thats all and worked perfectly.

[image: Android Device Manager Factory Reset in Visual studio]